# Problema retornando sh: 0: -c requires an argument

Tags: python-2.7

Bom galera seguinte, eu tenho este código abaixo para python 2.7:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import os

if len(sys.argv) <= 3:
    for comando in sys.argv[1:]:
        shell = os.system(comando)
        print comando
```

porém quando vou ai terminal digitar ls -la ele me retornar o seguinte:

```
┌─[backz]@[NoSafe]:~/hk/programacao/python/manipular_arquivos
└──> $ ./comando.py ls -la
arq.txt  comando.py  executar_comando.py  grep.py  os  sys  usando_argv.py
ls
sh: 0: -c requires an argument
-la
```

isso apenas se eu digitar um comando completo no terminal como ls -la. Se eu digitar ls, pwd, id e etc comandos únicos né, ele me retorna o resultado numa boa. Problema acorre para comando compostos.
Buscando pela internet percebi que se trata algo direto da shell linux, não se trata de um erro é sim de um retorno na qual ele não consegue identificar.

Gostaria da ajuda de vcs ou é tem alguma outra forma de efetuar o processo com comandos compostos obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está iterando sobre os argumentos da linha de comando, assim cada um deles será executado individualmente pelo `os.system`:

```
if len(sys.argv) <= 3:              # arv = ['./comando.py', 'ls', '-la']
    for comando in sys.argv[1:]:    # arv[1:] = ['ls', '-la']
        shell = os.system(comando)  # comando = 'ls' (1ª iteração)
        print comando               #         = '-la' (2ª iteração)
```

O primeiro (`ls`) não está recebendo argumento nenhum (veja na sua saída que ele mostra só os nomes dos arquivos, numa linha só) e o segundo é que está causando esse erro estranho (que não sei o que significa, pois não tenho muita familiaridade com `os.system`).

Acho que o que você quer é pegar os argumentos do segundo pra frente e recombiná-los em uma string, separada por espaços (nota: não testei).

```
if len(sys.argv) <= 3:               # arv = ['./comando.py', 'ls', '-la']
    comando = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:]) # arv[1:] = ['ls', '-la']
    shell = os.system(comando)       # comando = 'ls -la'
    print comando
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @mgibsonbr resolveu meu problema.